# If I set an itemController in a #each, is there any way to set a binding on that itemController?

Tags: ember.js

If I do

```
{{#each widget in widgets itemController='special_widget'}}
```

is there any way to bind a value in the current context to a property of (each) itemController that gets created? (the reason is that the itemController needs to know the selected widget and this usage is in a view. So currently the itemController only knows the parentController context, and can't access any values that were bound to the view it is in. I will eventually refactor to a component, but that's a largish task I want to postpone for a couple sprints)

I tried:

```
{{#each widget in widgets itemController='special_widget' selectedWidgetBinding='whatever'}}
```

and

```
{{#each widget in widgets itemController='special_widget' itemControllerSelectedWidgetBinding='whatever'}}
```

Comment: I am assuming that refactoring to a component will solve my problem, because itemController.parentController will now be the component controller, and thus have access to bindings on the component. Is this true?

Comment: Couldn't you have your itemController 'needs' the parentController which would know the selectedWidget?

Comment: well, I was already doing `Ember.computed.alias('parentController.selectedWidget')`. The problem is that the view now has to be used multiple times for multiple simultaneous "selectedWidget"s

Comment: okeydokey, I am refactoring to a component it seems.